# Installing new headlights on Audi A6 C6 '05

Tags: headlight, lights, audi, retrofit

I have a C6 4F2 from 2005 (Sedan) and I'd like to (retro) fit new headlights.

Currently I have the non-xenon version without daytime running lights and as far as I know, no automatic height adjustment. (I have to set them manually)

These ones.
[image]
I'd like to buy a pair with an Xenon bulb, possibly with Daytime running lights, however I don't really care about the DRL. 
Nothing fancy or aftermarket; just the 'standard' xenon-fitted units.

**Other than actually buying
 an Xenon kit and the headlight unit itself, what else do I have to keep in mind?**

Is there more to it than that?

The unit I'm talking about looks like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't fussed about adding DRLs to it then you shouldn't have to replace the headlight unit itself, you should be able to just purchase a HID kit and fit them to the existing units.

NB: You don't say whereabouts in the world you are located but there may be local regulations surrounding HID lights - some places require cars with them to have headlight washers and auto-leveling fitted.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your information. I live in the Netherlands, Europe. I notice that, even though my units are pretty clear, that the lights just aren't as bright enough? I personally also like the xenon look and lights, hence my reason to ask for it! Thanks tho!

Comment: An [aftermarket HID kit](https://xenon24.nl/xenon-kits.html) should be just the ticket then, 2005 is around the crossover to when Audi started using CANBUS so I'm not sure if yours will have it or not. Definitely check that before ordering anything as not having a CANBUS-suitable kit when the car expects one will result in the car continually thinking the bulbs have gone!

Comment: Thank you! That is some really useful info right there ;). I was also afraid of the computer not excepting different lights or what not. I'll have that in mind!
I'm pretty sure my lights are connected to canbus because I do get errors/warning when a light is out.

Comment: @Paramone They probably are CANBUS then.. the appropriate kit is slightly more expensive IIRC but it's worth it IMO. Hope you enjoy the new lights.. my C5 S6 has the factory Xenons and they are ace :)

Comment: Thanks man! They indeed are a bit more expensive. First I need to find me some units! I'm trying to give my car a more cleaner look. Maybe black it out (profesionally). It'd definately look way nicer with a good pair of xenons than stock halogen ones.  Cheers!